# How to find duplicate values (not rows) in an entire pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Consider this dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'one': list('abcd'),
                        'two': list('efgh'),
                        'three': list('ajha')})
  one two three
0   a   e     a
1   b   f     j
2   c   g     h
3   d   h     a
```

How can I output all duplicate values and their respective index? The output can look something like this.

```
  id value
0  2     h
1  3     h
2  0     a
3  0     a
4  3     a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `.melt` + `.duplicated`:

```py
x = df.reset_index().melt("index")
print(
    x.loc[x.duplicated(["value"], keep=False), ["index", "value"]]
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .rename(columns={"index": "id"})
)
```

Prints:

```
   id value
0   0     a
1   3     h
2   0     a
3   2     h
4   3     a
```

Comment: Many replied quickly but I appreciate the simplicity of your approach. In fact, makes me feel silly for not thinking of this. Thanks!

Comment: @user2962397 Thanks, happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

We can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the DataFrame, use [`Series.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) to keep only where `value` is [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) then [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) to convert to a DataFrame:

```
new_df = (
    df.stack()  # Convert to Long Form
        .droplevel(-1).rename_axis('id')  # Handle MultiIndex
        .loc[lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False)]  # Filter Values
        .reset_index(name='value')  # Make Series a DataFrame
)
```

`new_df`:

```
   id value
0   0     a
1   0     a
2   2     h
3   3     h
4   3     a
```

Answer (score 2):

I used here `melt` to reshape and `duplicated(keep=False)` to select the duplicates:

```
(df.rename_axis('id')
   .reset_index()
   .melt(id_vars='id')
   .loc[lambda d: d['value'].duplicated(keep=False), ['id','value']]
   .sort_values(by='id')
   .reset_index(drop=True)
 )
```

Output:

```
    id value
0   0     a
1   0     a
2   2     h
3   3     h
4   3     a
```

Comment: I believe `loc` with `lambda` would have less overhead than `assign` + `query` + `drop`. `df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index').loc[lambda d: d['value'].duplicated(keep=False), ['index','value']]` (although that would be almost identical to [Andrej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69229443/15497888))

Comment: Yes you're right, I just didn't think of it at the time ;)